# Centralized Error Handling & Reporting for node.js

Tags: node.js, express, exception

I want to have a system which will either send me a text message or email based on severity of error on respective occurrence. I have done some research on the subject but I haven't been able to simplify matters.

All in all my end goal is to get notification whenever something is going wrong with my production server. In case of serious issues which are not caught at all I have used process's `uncaughtException` and for specific routes which are called via separate API calls I can simply use try catch blocks.

My first issue is I cannot handle errors thrown from different routes directly via my main server file.

Second is I'll have to write same kinda' code in every route for exception handling. If something could just listen to all the errors from main server file then I can do things easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an error handling middleware in Express:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack);
  // do whatever you need to send a notification
  res.status(500).send('Internal error');
});
```

See the documentation on the error handling in Express:

- https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Everything you ask about is explained very well there.

Comment: thanks for your time rsp. I did try this btw but perhaps I haven't placed it properly.

Comment: In one of the API's listener(route) function - let's say if there is a reference error and I want it to be logged via a central module but this middle ware via express isn't listening to it.